# If a program is compatible with Ubuntu, will it be compatible with Ubuntu Touch?

Tags: 14.04, ubuntu-touch, touchscreen

I really want to get a tablet PC and install Ubuntu Touch on it.

**Will every package that I've installed in my desktop installation of Ubuntu (`14.04`) run in Ubuntu Touch?**

Is Ubuntu Touch simply Ubuntu with some tweaks to Unity (or whatever graphical package it uses) to aid with touchscreen devices?

Comment: Very short answer: *Ubuntu Touch will eventually be the same as Ubuntu, and run the same software. However tablets and smartphones lack the processing power and storage of a 'fat client' (a PC), so emphasis is being placed on 'web apps' and other lightweight applications. These will also be able to run on Ubuntu (desktop).* **There is plenty of information / discussions on this.** Do more research ..

Comment: @david6 Sounds to me like I may have to add some repositories but once I do that it should work fine. Not looking to play any games or 3D stuff. Just Sublime Text, Rhythm Box, Wine (nothing crazy), LibreOffice ect

Comment: Wine is Windows XP/7 emulation, under Linux. *Do **NOT** expect this to run on a tablet very well.*